# Leaflet Map in Angular4 throwing errors

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

template :

```
<div id="mapid" style="height: 500px"></div>
```

I have installed leaflet and the typings for leaflet. When an error showed up saying map container was not found, i added it 's import.

controller :

```
    import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from 
    '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import { Map } from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-leafletmap',
  templateUrl: './leafletmap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leafletmap.component.css']
})
export class LeafletmapComponent implements OnInit {
  mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([29.6516, -82.3248], 13);

  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}',
   {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, 
    <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: '*****************************'
  }).addTo(mymap);

  popup = L.popup();
  marker: any;

  onMapClick(e) {
    if (marker != undefined)
      mymap.removeLayer(marker)
    marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, { draggable: true });
    mymap.addLayer(marker);
    popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString()).openOn(mymap);
  }
  mymap.on('zoomend', function() {
    console.log(mymap.getZoom());
  })
  mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I am not sure if this is the way to pass access tokens and initializing variables in typescript as I wrote this code following a tutorial that was using regular Javascript.

Comment: Likely due to the multi-line string. If it's on multiple lines you need add the strings together: `'line1' + 'line2' + 'line3'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently worked with leaflet , so I post my code that is fully workable here. Please try it yourself.

I use next npm module: `npm install @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet --save`
See:
https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet

**component.ts**

```
private map: L.Map;

options = {
        layers: [
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 15 })
        ],
        zoom: 4,
        center: L.latLng([39.878868, -100.357010])
    };

onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
    this.map = map;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div leaflet
     [leafletOptions]="options"
     (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        LeafletModule.forRoot() // Don't forget to include leaflet here.
    ]
```

You can try my basic variant and then if it works, you can add your options and your login to `onMapReady` function.

UPD: If you want to reference something from leaflet, e.g. MapOptions in specific component, simply import leaflet in this way. `import * as L from 'leaflet';` then use `L.Map` , `L.MapOptions`, etc.

UPD2: Also it's essential to install types `npm install @types/leaflet`

Comment: `node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/dist/leaflet/core/leaflet.directive.d.ts (2,37): Module '"leaflet"' has no exported member 'MapOptions' `     this is the error I am getting right now.

Comment: See my edits. You need to do another npm install `npm install @types/leaflet`.

Comment: There was a brief period a couple weeks ago where the 0.7.x version of ```@types/leaflet``` was published as the most recent version. This was causing issues because 0.7.x is incompatible with Leaflet 1.x, which is what ngx-leaflet is built against.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message like you: `Module '"leaflet"' has no exported member 'MapOptions'`). For me it worked to uninstall the leaflet-types (`npm uninstall @types/leaflet`)